# My Python items aren't adding to the list, len isn't changing after recalling

Tags: python

Alright, I'm making a game of sorts... I've done it with append as well -_-

When I call back and add the next item(i.e. #2 after doing #1) I get just that item in the print out...

such as this:

```
>  1
You put your Hatchet into the bag
Press enter to add more items
['Hatchet']
>  
>  2
You put your Toothbrush into the bag
Press enter to add more items
['Toothbrush']
```

I'd like for the bag to get more items in it and once the bag reaches three items it takes me to the next 'level'.  I can't seem to add the items to the bag and keep them in the bag and then monitor the growing len(bag).  If I call back the len(bag) it's always stuck back on 1.  Is this because of the 'return' function I'm using? or is it something else? I figure I can try coding so that it goes into a new list with new bag after entering one item(seems like a ton of excessive code, but would work).  I'm also pretty confident there is tons of excessive code in this script, I'm extremely new to Python and am doing an assignment/exercise from a book.  I appreciate the help in advance!!

```
def beginning():
    print 'Hello'

def func():
    firstitem=raw_input(">  ")
    bag=[]
    limit=len(bag)
    a="Hatchet"
    b="Toothbrush"
    c="Map"

    if firstitem=="1":
        bag.insert(1, 'Hatchet')
        print 'You put your %s into the bag' % a
        print 'Press enter to add more items'
        print bag
        limit=len(bag)
        if limit == int(3):
            beginning()
        item=raw_input(">  ")
        return func()
    if firstitem=="2":
        bag.insert(2, 'Toothbrush')
        print 'You put your %s into the bag' % b
        print 'Press enter to add more items'
        print bag
        limit=len(bag)
        if limit == int(3):
            beginning()
        item=raw_input(">  ")
        return func()
    if firstitem=="3":
        bag.insert(3, 'Map')
        print 'You put your %s into the bag' % c
        print 'Press enter to add more items'
        print bag
        limit=len(bag)

    if limit == int(3):
            beginning()
        item=raw_input(">  ")
        return func()
```

OK so if I make the new func. is that under the existing one? or complete new?

Comment: changing it now!good quick help!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're adding something to `bag`, but then you're recursing into the start of `func` again, where it has a different scope. It then assigns `[]` to `bag`, leaving it empty. Something you could do is make `func` take an optional argument:

```
def func(bag=None):
    if bag is None:
        bag = []
    # ...
    return func(bag)
```

Additionally, `append` probably really is the right thing to do here.

Comment: does my limit work though? where is len(bag) gets to be more than int(3) it will take me to next lvl?

Answer (score 0):

bag is a list not a dict.  If you want to add items to a list, you should use append.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you always have the only one item in bag list is because you recreate it each time you call your function so you need to find a way how to correctly initialize it. Also it is better to use append instead of insert in your case. Please find below my sample code(not sure that this is a good idea to write code this way - so don't beat me too much for it):

```
def beginning():
    print 'Hello'
    return []

def func(bag):
    item = raw_input("Enter your choice here >  ")
    limit = len(bag)
    things = {'1':"Hatchet", '2':"Toothbrush", '3':"Map", '77':'Leave', '100':'backward'}
    if things.get(item).lower() == 'leave':
        print 'Bye'
        return
    elif things.get(item).lower() == 'backward':
        while len(bag)!=0:
            print bag, bag.pop()
        return
    bag.append(things.get(item))
    print 'You put your %s into the bag' % things.get(item)
    print 'Press enter to add more items'
    print bag
    if len(bag) == 3:
        bag = beginning()
    return func(bag)

func(beginning())
```

Comment: how else would I write it? Like I said rather new... Not rele using classes but I assume I could use more classes? Also how do I import from other files? Like my game is getting really long(code wise) can I import some of these functions from other files?

Comment: It could be rewrite by a dozen of ways. Sure that you could use classes too. In order to import you can use 'import': http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#import . Using this statement(or 'from <module> import <func, class, var>') you can import anything you want from the other files.

Comment: hmm alright that sounds good... I got the script working, but I was taught to write the game backwards(where beginning is at the end) this the next level in the game is above this one in the script and I'd like to refer back to 'bag' and what is in it.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you simply would like to proceed with list and to delete one item per iteration you can use 'pop' method - if bag = ["Hatchet", "Toothbrush", "Map"] then if you call thing = bag.pop() >>> thing contains now 'Map', while bag contains ["Hatchet", "Toothbrush"].

Comment: hmmm... well I wanted to have it so based off the items they brought the story would change, if they brought the map(I actually have about 10 things on the list, they can only bring 3) they would be able to view it and see the surrounding area or which direction to travel, if they brought a sword they move slow and if they don't have map they don't know the direction to go and have to guess etc...

Comment: ultimately I'd like the bag(created in this function) to be universal once completed... (I know there is global function but I imagine it wouldn't be usable in this case?)

Comment: It is not clear for me what you really want. I have modified code to show you how proceed backward in list.

Comment: ya? that might help...  Basically I'm making a game, I was taught the game goes in reverse order... So above the code you see here I have the next level after you pack everything, I'd like to be able to access the items in the bag(that you chose) in the next levels, but the contents of the bag will almost never be the same because you can only take 3 things and I have 10 options.  Thus when I call 'bag' in the next level it says 'bag' is undefined... I'll add u on Linkedin

Comment: Ok, you can find my skype at linkedin if it neccessary